# How to change push notification alert sound

Tags: iphone

I am trying to customize a push notification alert. I copied one sound file to the application bundle and set the sound file name in the push notification payload to that of the new file name, But the sound is not playing. How can I change the push notification alert sound?

Answer (score 0):

Try one aiff demo sound for push notification also make sure your device is not mute.

Comment: @PrasanthTR: please accept this answer by clicking checkmark next to it so we now it's been answered already